# Context Menu on ListView inside Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, contextmenu

I've searched everywhere and I also tried every code I looked into but unfortunately none of them worked. :( I already added registerForContextMenu() method but it still won't pop a menu when i click on an item in my list. Please help. I'm going crazy already. :( Here's what I got so far...

```
public class BorrowersFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
Button btnSearch,btnGetAll;

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public BorrowersFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BorrowersFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BorrowersFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BorrowersFragment fragment = new BorrowersFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

/*@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_borrowers, container, false);
}*/
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View borrowerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_borrowers, container, false);
    btnSearch = (Button) borrowerView.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    //btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnGetAll = (Button) borrowerView.findViewById(R.id.btnGetAll);
    //btnGetAll.setOnClickListener(this);

    BorrowerDBHelper repo = new BorrowerDBHelper(this.getContext());
    UserDBHelper repoUser = new UserDBHelper(this.getContext());
    User user = repoUser.getUserInfo();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> borrowerList =  repo.getBorrowerList(user.getId());
    if(borrowerList.size()!=0) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) borrowerView.findViewById(R.id.borrowerListView);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( BorrowersFragment.this.getContext(),borrowerList, R.layout.view_borrower, new String[] { "id","full_name"}, new int[] {R.id.borrower_Id, R.id.borrower_name});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"No student!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return  borrowerView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.view_profile_item, Menu.NONE, "View Profile");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.view_payments_item, Menu.NONE, "View Payment History");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.add_payment_item, Menu.NONE, "Add Payment");
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.view_profile_item:
            Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1a was chosen");
            return true;
        case R.id.view_payments_item:
            Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1b was chosen");
            return true;
        case R.id.add_payment_item:
            Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1b was chosen");
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

/*@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}*/

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Please do note that this fragment is called/shown when I choose it from a navigation drawer which is inside a MainActivity. 
Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to open a menu when user clicks on a `ListView` item?

So you can simply set an `OnLongClickListener` (or a simple `OnClickListener` depending on what you are trying to do) on the items and open an :

> android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    PopupMenu menu = new   PopupMenu(YourActivity.this, listItem);
    menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_file, menu.getMenu());
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.your_first_menu_item:
            // do something
            break;
        }
        return false;
      }
   });
   menu.show();
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forgive my innocence... this is so embarassing. its actually working. I just have to long click it.

XD I'm so sorry for the waste of time. Cheers everyone.